# Do any of these car movements near the end of Orphan Black season 2 episode 3 (& start of 4) make any sense or are they even possible?

Tags: continuity, orphan-black

In the TV series Orphan Black season 2 episode 3, a corporate agent is hunting for Sarah, who left a hidden location in a truck.

> (I assume the agent was able to find the location because he was part of the trap. Ok, makes sense.)

She drives to a remote rural location down a dead-end road in the woods. How then does the police officer happen to come to exactly that house looking for her?

How does the corporate agent have any idea to come to that region to look for them?

After the corporate agent gets warned off,

> how does he then end up also coming exactly to that dead end road and choosing there go get out on foot?

Was he planning to spend a week in a random town examining every house in the countryside?

Then in episode 4,

> After Sarah is abducted by the corp agent, how did the boyfriend manage to take the girl to another hidden safe location, and then get ahead of Sarah and the agent's car and manage to ram them? How would he know where they were going, and have time to drop off the girl and then get ahead of them?

Answer (score 1):

> How then does the police officer happen to come to exactly that house looking for her?

The police officer was probably just doing the rounds and asking residents of each household if they had seen "some shoplifters" ("a mom with a little girl and another guy"). There is no indication that he actually had any suspicion that they might be at Cal's house.

> How does the corporate agent have any idea to come to that region to look for them?

Cal's home was not too far away from the birdwatcher's house (as evidenced by the fact that Sarah, Kira, and Felix were able to get there in less than a day). Daniel Rosen (whom you call the "corporate agent") works for the highly resourceful Dyad Institute. So one possibility is that they had already been keeping tabs on Cal (father of Kira), knew he where lived, and so Rosen guessed (correctly) that Sarah, Kira, and Felix might have gone to Cal's home.

> After Sarah is abducted by the corp agent, how did the boyfriend manage to take the girl to another hidden safe location, and then get ahead of Sarah and the agent's car and manage to ram them? How would he know where they were going, and have time to drop off the girl and then get ahead of them?

When Sarah and Cal ("the boyfriend") do reunite with Kira ("the girl"), Kira is in the woods. So, Cal probably simply told Kira to run to those woods (and didn't have to "take" her all the way there).

Cal has lived in the area for some time, so is probably very familiar with the roads in the area. The area is very sparsely populated, so probably doesn't have too many complicated roads. He can easily guess the direction they are headed, then speed towards the appropriate junction where he can confront their car. Also, it's Sarah who's driving the car and she wasn't exactly speeding.